# ranges::views::enumerate capturing by reference or by value? How can we tell?

Tags: c++, range-v3

In the following code, `auto [i, e]` and `auto&& [i, ee]` both bind `std::pair<int, T&>` rather than `std::pair<int, T>`. Could some explain how could have known this without testing empirically? I assume it's the range-v3 implementation. Is there a case where you would want to use `auto&&` rather than `auto`?

```cpp
auto container = std::array<int,3>{ 1,2,3 };

for (std::pair<int, int> p : ranges::views::enumerate(container))
    p.second = 0; //Bad, of course 
print(container);

for (auto [i, e] : ranges::views::enumerate(container))
    e = 0; //Okay???
print(container);

for (auto&& [i, ee] : ranges::views::enumerate(container))
    ee = 42; //Okay???
print(container);

> [1,2,3]
> [0,0,0]
> [42,42,42]
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b7vrsxqK4

Comment: I mean, why not just use [`for (auto&& [index, element] : ranges::views::enumerate(container))`](https://godbolt.org/z/8Wc3vr1ah)?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Okay, I didn't understand correctly what && does. I thought it would move the elements from the container

Comment: No, it just uses `int&&` to bind the index and `std::atomic_int&` to bind the element, that's all, there is no move operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: use `static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(variable_name)>);`

---

I was confused because typically in the ranged for loop when the `*` operator is called on the iterator it returns a `T&`, so you must add a ref-qualifier to get a reference rather than a copy.

```cpp
for(auto& el : container)
--------------- 
auto& el = *it; // reference
```

```cpp
for(auto el : container)
--------------- 
auto el = *it; // copy
```

However, when `*` returns a `std::pair<int, T&>` you can't `auto&` anymore, but now `auto` will work correctly since it is the reference of the pair that is being copy assigned not reference inside the pair `T&`.

Combining this with structured binding, it's quite confusing what's actually happening since `el`, below, is actually a reference:

```cpp
for (auto [i, el] : views::enumerate(container))
        el = 3; // OKAY!
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the type when you dereference an iterator to a given range, you can

```cpp
template<typename... Args> void whatis();
int main() 
{
    auto container = std::array<int, 3>{ 1, 2, 3 };
    auto it = ranges::views::enumerate(container).begin();
    using traits = std::iterator_traits<decltype(it)>;
    whatis<traits::reference>();
}
```

Which will tell you that the infered type in `for(auto p : enumerate(container))` will be `ranges::common_pair<unsigned int,int &>`

Similarly you can find the type of `ranges::views::enumerate(container)` is `ranges::detail::index_view<unsigned int,int>,struct ranges::ref_view<class std::array<int,3>>>`.

From there you can start looking into the source code. `enumerate` passes to `zip` which passes to `all` which uses template speciaization resolution

```cpp
/// If it's a view already, pass it though.
template<typename T>
static constexpr auto from_range_(T&& t, std::true_type, detail::ignore_t,
    detail::ignore_t)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

/// If it is container-like, turn it into a view, being careful
/// to preserve the Sized-ness of the range.
template<typename T>
static constexpr auto from_range_(T&& t, std::false_type, std::true_type,
    detail::ignore_t)
{
    return ranges::views::ref(t);
}

/// Not a view and not an lvalue? If it's a borrowed_range, then
/// return a subrange holding the range's begin/end.
template<typename T>
static constexpr auto from_range_(T&& t, std::false_type, std::false_type,
    std::true_type)
{
    return make_subrange(static_cast<T&&>(t));
}

public:
template(typename T)(
    /// \pre
    requires range<T&> AND viewable_range<T>)
    constexpr auto operator()(T&& t) const
{
    return all_fn::from_range_(static_cast<T&&>(t),
        meta::bool_<view_<uncvref_t<T>>>{},
        std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{},
        meta::bool_<borrowed_range<T>>{});
}
```

You can then look into `ref_view` and see that it does do what the name suggests (refer to the underlying container).