# How to combine views::enumerate and views::filter?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a container that I want to filter.
I also need the index of the items later.
For that I want to use something like this:

```cpp
auto items_to_remove = items | ranges::view::enumerate | ranges::view::filter(/*???*/);
```

What type do I have to use for the filter function?

Edit: Here is my code/ error message:

```cpp
auto f = [](const auto& pair) {
            return true;
        };
auto items_to_remove = level.items | ranges::views::enumerate | ranges::views::filter(f);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an `enumerate::view` makes the element that is passed to the filter a

```cpp
ranges::common_pair<size_t, int&>&
```

So, just take the `common_pair` by `const&`.

```cpp
auto f = [](const ranges::common_pair<size_t, int&>& pair) {
    // filter on pair.first to filter on the index
    // filter on pair.second to filter on the actual value in the vector
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1q5oh3o6r)

or simply:

```cpp
auto f = [](auto&& pair) { ... }
```

Then

```cpp
for (auto&&[idx, element] : v | views::enumerate | views::filter(f)) {
    element += 100;                            // elements are mutable here
    std::cout << idx << ' ' << element << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h47qoKT15)

Comment: Also there's not point in `auto&&[idx, element]`. Although I suppose you can put `&&` everywhere and it will always do the right thing i.e. `auto& [.., ..]` vs `auto [.., ..]`

Comment: thank you, but the first approach won't even compile : `no operator "|" matches these operands. operand types are: ranges::zip_view<ranges::detail::index_view<unsigned int, ptrdiff_t>, ranges::ref_view<std::vector<raid::item_info, std::allocator<raid::item_info>>>> | ranges::views::view_closure<ranges::detail::bind_back_fn_<ranges::views::filter_base_fn, type>>
`
and the second won't compile either.

Comment: Yes, sorry. So I guess `[](const auto& pair){ ... }` compiles but not `[](auto& pair){ ... }`

Comment: @Raildex The first approach compiles fine. See the first demo. I suggest using `auto&&` anyway though

Comment: @TomHuntington Yes, const& works but not non-const&

Comment: @TedLyngmo basic c++11. I guess I program in c++ without knowing much about it

Comment: @TomHuntington :-) It's just that the `common_pair` is a temporary so one must either take it by value or by `const&` to prolong its lifetime.

Comment: @TomHuntington using `const auto&` does not help.

Comment: @Raildex [Yes it does](https://godbolt.org/z/8Ta43da8q)

Comment: @Raildex Using the variable names you use in your question still works like I showed in the answer. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/76YvqW54h). You need to provide a [mre] so we can see why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Raildex the visual studio linter always shows that error I believe, you have to actually compile to know if range-v3 code is right

Comment: @Raildex try with just a `vector<int>` and get that to work first. Then solve the problem with your `raid::item_info` type

Comment: @TomHuntington you are right. it compiles fine. Intellisense is just dumb once again

Answer (score 1):

You should use auto lambdas with ranges, adding it static asserts if necessary.

If you don't want a copy happening you can simply have a predicate that takes its argument by value.

```cpp
auto pred = [](auto pair) -> bool { return /*do something with T&*/ pair.second; };
```

The instantiated type of `pair` will be `ranges::common_pair<size_t, T&>` which you can copy around without copying the underlying `T`. You can call `pair.second` to get a `T&` in you predicate.

Shower around the following static assert just to be sure or delete the copy constructor for `T` because it is a very annoying when this copy turns out to be your bug.

```cpp
std::vector<std::optional<T>> elements;
for (auto [index, opt] : elements
    | ranges::views::filter([](auto pair) -> bool { return pair.second; })
    )
{
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(opt)>);
    opt->MethodOfT();
}
```

To understand why `opt` is a reference here see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70704890/rangesviewsenumerate-capturing-by-reference-or-by-value-how-can-we-tell)

Comment: I didn't see your answer before. Yes, `auto pair` works fine too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::pair<int, T>`. `.first` is the index. `.second` is the element.

```
int main() {
    auto v = std::vector{0, 1, 23, 3, 42, 50, 81, 4, -1};
    auto f = [](std::pair<int, int> p) { return p.first % 2 == 0 && p.second >= 10; };
    for (auto [i, e] : v | views::enumerate | views::filter(f)) {
        std::cout << i << " -> " << e << "\n";
    }
}
```

<sup>([Godbolt Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:14,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:14,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:14,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:14,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Crange/v3/all.hpp%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++using+namespace+ranges%3B%0A++++auto+v+%3D+std::vector%7B0,+1,+23,+3,+42,+50,+81,+4,+-1%7D%3B%0A++++auto+f+%3D+%5B%5D(std::pair%3Cint,+int%3E+p)+%7B+return+p.first+%25+2+%3D%3D+0+%26%26+p.second+%3E%3D+10%3B+%7D%3B%0A++++for+(auto+%5Bi,+e%5D+:+v+%7C+views::enumerate+%7C+views::filter(f))+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+%22+-%3E+%22+%3C%3C+e+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.75156902803084,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:rangesv3,ver:%270120%27)),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.14556842336175,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:35.85443157663825,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:44.24843097196916,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))</sup>

Comment: what if i want T to be a Reference? (i dont want a copy)?

Comment: @Raildex See Ted's answer of using `&&`.